# how can I get hh:mm time from ISO without any time difference

Tags: javascript, react-native, momentjs

```
createAlarm({
    active: true,
    date: picked_Date.toISOString(),
    message: 'sample alarm',
    snooze: 1,
});
```

I created an alarm using DatePicker(react-native-date-picker), and react-native-simple-alarm

```
...
<Text>{date}</Text>  // 2022-02-16T08:47:25.352Z
```

i just want HH : MM value in 24hours, like 13:42, 09:50 or 22:10.
so i tried this code

```
<Text>{moment(date).format('hh:mm')}</Text> // 05:47
```

This did give me hh:mm formed value,
but the value was not the same as my computer and ios simulator
it was supposed to 08:47, cause the {date} was 2022-02-16T08:47:25.352Z

How can I get rid of the time difference?
and set moment's time zone globally as same as the hardware(simulator or phone)?

Comment: Timezones, it's always timezones! I'm guessing that you're not in a UTC/GMT +0 timezone. JavaScript will always present you the local time and it understands the difference from UTC.

Comment: @phuzi I'm in Time zone in Seoul (GMT+9). Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `moment.utc()` . it will adjust your input time to UTC so you will the time you want.
also `hh:mm` will give 12 hour clock time so you will need `HH:mm` for 24 hour clock

```js
//12 hr clock
var a = moment.utc('2022-02-16T08:47:25.352Z').format('hh:mm');
var b = moment.utc('2022-02-16T18:47:25.352Z').format('hh:mm');

console.log(a)
console.log(b)


//24 hr clock
var c = moment.utc('2022-02-16T08:47:25.352Z').format('HH:mm');
var d = moment.utc('2022-02-16T18:47:25.352Z').format('HH:mm');

console.log(c)
console.log(d)
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.2.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```